# Populate List<T> using Dataset?

Tags: c#, list, dataset

I have a class `Book`:

```
public class Book
{
    public int ID;
    public string BookName;
    public List<string> BookImageUrl;
}
```

I want to populate this class from dataset which returns `ID`, `BookName` and multiple image of a single book.

Comment: When does JSON come into play here? What have you tried so far?

Comment: You can use EntityFramework to create a context to the Database and populate the Book Object.

http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/

You can use JSON Converter to later convert the Book object into JSON.

http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter.htm

Comment: But I want to use DataSet ?

Comment: ok..so all the data that you have fetched from database is present in a dataset and you want to create a list of `Book` objects populated with values of all the columns in respective properties. Correct? You can rephrase your question a bit. We are unable to get the role of JSON format which you have mentioned in the title of the post.

Comment: @RBT yes correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start thinking in the direction of getting List of books using below code:

```
DataSet ds = null;

//populate the dataset ds from SQL Server using ADO .Net

/*
Your database would have two tables:
Books : containing Id, BookName columns -> This will get populated in Tables[0] of dataset
BookImages: containing BookId, BookImageUrl columns -> This will get populated in Tables[1] of dataset

Here BookId column in BookImages table is foreign key referring to Id column in Books table 
             */

//tables[0] contains main attributes of a book e.g. Name, Id etc.
DataTable dataTab = ds.Tables[0];

var bookList = dataTab.AsEnumerable().Select(x => new Book                      {
               ID = int.Parse(x["Id"].ToString()),
               BookName = x["BookName"].ToString(),
             });

/*tables[1] contains detailed attributes of a book e.g. book image Urls
         * */
DataTable imageTab = ds.Tables[1];

foreach (var book in bookList)
{
    book.BookImageUrl = imageTab.AsEnumerable()
                        .Where(x => Convert.ToInt32(x["BookId"]) == book.ID)
                        .Select(x => x["BookImageUrl"].ToString()).ToList();
}
```

Comment: thanks that's help a lot. Btw what about "public List<string> BookImageUrl"

Comment: I've updated my answer for populating `BookImageUrl` assuming a basic database schema. Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation :)